# Vaadin Image in a Grid not showing

Tags: image, vaadin, treegrid, vaadin-flow

I'm trying to display a tiny little image (16x16 pixels) in a TreeGrid Column.

```
 treeGrid.addComponentColumn(i -> new Image("file://c:/temp/reddot.png", "alt")).setHeader("Preview");
```

In my IDE, this file url is underlined, I can click it, it opens the image in my browser. So, the file seems ok and exists. 
But somehow, it does not appear in the grid column and the "alt" text doesn't appear either.
Hm. Anyone any idea what's going wrong ? Unfortunatly I don't see any error messages...

thanks,
Thorsten

PS: I'm using Version 13.

Comment: Can you try putting all resources that your application needs in the appropriate `frontend` folder? [Here](https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-10-and-static-resources) is a blog that explains where your frontend folder needs to be located.

Comment: Tried it - but since I use spring boot and am stil in "development mode", I have noch real jar/war file. So it didn't work. But thanks anyway for that link. Very interessting.

Comment: IIRC spring boot also uses a jar/war in the end. After you run your app, see if there is a `target` folder in your project root. It should contain the jar/war.

Comment: Create a folder `src/main/webapp/frontend/img` and put your image in there. When creating your Vaadin `Image` object, use this path: `new Image("frontend/img/reddot.png", "alt")`

Comment: suggestion for non related code improvement: If you always show the same image for all rows, you can create the Image once beforehand, and use the same image instance in the addComponentColumn. If the image depends on certain attributes of the respective item, then ignore this comment.

Comment: You probably need to use a [component renderer](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid.html#using-component-renderers) for that column.

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the grid cell? Is the `<img>` tag present?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put image under `META-INF/resources`. Then you could reference image directly by name like this : `Image im=new Image("kissa.jpg","Random picture");`

Otherwise, you could create a inside and then reference mentioning also folder. In the picture below I have this set-up
[image: Image location]

And this is the output :
[image]

The whole code:

```
    TreeGrid<Person> grid = new TreeGrid<>(Person.class);
    grid.setHierarchyColumn("name");
    grid.addComponentColumn(e->{
    if(e.getName().equals("daughter")) {
            Image im=new  Image("test/cat.jpg","Random picture");
            im.setWidth("200px");
            im.setHeight("150px");
            return im;}
    else { 
           Image im=new Image("kissa.jpg","Random picture"); 
           im.setWidth("200px");
           im.setHeight("150px");
           return im;}}).setHeader("Cat");
    Person dad = new Person("dad", null);
    Person son = new Person("son", dad);
    Person daughter = new Person("daughter", dad);
    List<Person> all = Arrays.asList(dad, son, daughter);

    all.forEach(p -> grid.getTreeData().addItem(p.getParent(), p));

    add(grid);
```

The example of TreeGrid is copied from here: [Using new features with the LTS version: case TreeGrid](https://vaadin.com/blog/using-new-features-with-the-lts-version-case-treegrid)